# XCode throws Sigabrt error whenever I run due to IBOutletCollection

Tags: xcode, ios5, iboutlet

I am creating an app for iOS 5 and I am getting the following error:

```
Assertion failure in -[UIRuntimeOutletCollectionConnection performConnect], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UIRuntimeOutletCollectionConnection.m:43
```

I have tried to debug the error and can see that it occurs because I connect an item to an IBOutletCollection.

The IBOutletCollection is being defined as follows:

```
@property (strong) IBOutletCollection(BallButton) NSSet *Balls;
```

with

```
NSSet *Balls;
```

being defined as an instance variable.

Whenever I have not connected a Ball to the collection in interface builder the app will load fine. However, as soon as any of the balls are added to the collection then I will get an error after the ViewController and all the balls have been instantiated and before ViewDidLoad in the ViewController.

It was working fine and then I repositioned some of the layers and now I can't get rid of this error.

If anyone can help with even a suggestion of why this is happening or even just an iOS 5 example of using IBOutletCollection (in case I have done something wrong in the setup, but I don't think I have) then it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you `@synthesize` the property? What does that look like?

Comment: Hi Ken, I did synthesize with '@synthesize Balls;' So don't think that is the problem. I have resorted to ignoring the IBOutletCollection and using a workaround of retrieving the items from the view. To anyone who is also having difficulties with IBOutletCollection you can use the snippet of code below to avoid having to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using IBOutletCollection you can get the view that contains all the items you want in the collection and connect it using IBOutlet. Then use:

```
- (NSSet *)getBallsFromView:(UIView *)view
{
    NSMutableSet *balls = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    for (UIView *subview in [view subviews]) 
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[BallButton class]])
            [balls addObject:(BallButton *)subview];
    }
}
```

This will retrieve all the items from the view that are of the specific type and then you can simply add them to the collection. This only gets all the items if they are directly on the view you are iterating through. If there a subviews that also contain items you want you will have to call this method recursively.

Answer (score 0):

IBOutletCollections should be declared as NSArray, you have it as NSSet. It should be written as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(BallButton) NSArray *Balls;
```